# "It is necessary <that he sell the house> <for him to sell the house>."

Tags: difference, subjunctives, infinitive-clauses

[usefulenglish.ru](https://usefulenglish.ru/grammar/present-subjunctive):
**(1)** *It is necessary that he sell the house*.
**(2)** *It is necessary for him to sell the house*.

Do (1) and (2) mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?
If they do, is it true that (1) is more natural in USA and (2) is more natural in UK?

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same. 1 is markedly formal - suitable for a legal document. Both are correct in both the US and UK, but 2 would be the simple, unmarked choice in British English.

Comment: James is correct, but your (1) is using what is called the SUBJUNCTIVE, a rather rare and formal grammatical case in English  (also seen in, say, "whether it BE cold or hot tomorrow").